# Perform Segue is not working after the in-app payment method is done

Tags: ios, swift

> ```
> @IBAction func PayFunc(_ sender: Any) {
>         
>         // Button to Handle the 15 Mintues for Kiinya Samba
>                for product in list{
>                    let prodID = product.productIdentifier
>                    if(prodID == "928.10883_2379"){
>                        p = product
>                        buyProduct()
>                     //Please Tell me if I am placing it in the right space
>                     makeNewPage()
>                    }
>                }
>     } '''
>     func buyProduct(){
>           print("buy " + p.productIdentifier)
>           let pay = SKPayment(product: p)
>           SKPaymentQueue.default().add(self)
>           SKPaymentQueue.default().add(pay as SKPayment)
>       }
>     func productsRequest(_ request: SKProductsRequest, didReceive response: SKProductsResponse) {
>            
>            // function takes care of the request to in app
>            print("product request")
>            let myProduct = response.products
>            for product in myProduct{
>                print("product added")//make the change to the alert box once testing is succesful
>                print(product.productIdentifier)
>                print(product.localizedTitle)
>                print(product.localizedDescription)
>                print(product.price)
>                
>                list.append(product)
>            }
>        }
>     func paymentQueueRestoreCompletedTransactionsFinished(_ queue: SKPaymentQueue) {
>            print("transaction restored")
>            for transaction in queue.transactions{
>                let t : SKPaymentTransaction = transaction
>                let prodID = t.payment.productIdentifier as String
>                
>                switch prodID{
>                case "928.10883_2379":
>                    print("Payment Made")
>                    makeSuccessAlert()
>                default:
>                    //in case in-app-payment id is not found
>                    print("IAP not found")
>                }
>            }
>         makeNewPage()
>        }
>     func paymentQueue(_ queue: SKPaymentQueue, updatedTransactions transactions: [SKPaymentTransaction]) {
>         
>         print("add payment")
>         
>         for transaction: AnyObject in transactions{
>             let trans = transaction as! SKPaymentTransaction
>             print(trans.error as Any)
>             
>             switch trans.transactionState {
>             case.purchased:
>                 print("buy ok, unlock IAP HERE")
>                 print(p.productIdentifier)
>                 
>                 let prodID = p.productIdentifier
>                 switch prodID {
>                     case "928.10883_2379":
>                         print("Payment Made")
>                         makeSuccessAlert()
>                     
>                     default:
>                         //in case in-app-payment id is not found
>                         print("IAP not found")
>                 }
>                 queue.finishTransaction(trans)
>             case .failed:
>                 print("buy error")
>                 queue.finishTransaction(trans)
>                 break;
>             default:
>                 print("Deafult")
>                 break
>             }
>         }
>         makeNewPage()
>     }
>     func makeNewPage(){
>         //created a function to activate the segue because it failed to work before
>         //The segue is a result of view to view connection
>         
>         self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "toMinutesKiinyaVC", sender: self)
>     }
>     func makeSuccessAlert(){
>         //Success Alert
>         let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Payment Made", message: "You payed for 15 mintue Tutoring", preferredStyle:
> ```
>
> UIAlertController.Style.alert)
> let okButton = UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: UIAlertAction.Style.default){
> action in  @IBAction func PayFunc(_ sender: Any) {
>
> ```
>         // Button to Handle the 15 Mintues for Kiinya Samba
>                for product in list{
>                    let prodID = product.productIdentifier
>                    if(prodID == "928.10883_2379"){
>                        p = product
>                        buyProduct()
>                     //Please Tell me if I am placing it in the right space
>                     makeNewPage()
>                    }
>                }
>     }
>     func buyProduct(){
>           print("buy " + p.productIdentifier)
>           let pay = SKPayment(product: p)
>           SKPaymentQueue.default().add(self)
>           SKPaymentQueue.default().add(pay as SKPayment)
>       }
>     func productsRequest(_ request: SKProductsRequest, didReceive response: SKProductsResponse) {
>            
>            // function takes care of the request to in app
>            print("product request")
>            let myProduct = response.products
>            for product in myProduct{
>                print("product added")//make the change to the alert box once testing is succesful
>                print(product.productIdentifier)
>                print(product.localizedTitle)
>                print(product.localizedDescription)
>                print(product.price)
>                
>                list.append(product)
>            }
>        }
>     func paymentQueueRestoreCompletedTransactionsFinished(_ queue: SKPaymentQueue) {
>            print("transaction restored")
>            for transaction in queue.transactions{
>                let t : SKPaymentTransaction = transaction
>                let prodID = t.payment.productIdentifier as String
>                
>                switch prodID{
>                case "928.10883_2379":
>                    print("Payment Made")
>                    makeSuccessAlert()
>                default:
>                    //in case in-app-payment id is not found
>                    print("IAP not found")
>                }
>            }
>         makeNewPage()
>        }
>     func paymentQueue(_ queue: SKPaymentQueue, updatedTransactions transactions: [SKPaymentTransaction]) {
>         
>         print("add payment")
>         
>         for transaction: AnyObject in transactions{
>             let trans = transaction as! SKPaymentTransaction
>             print(trans.error as Any)
>             
>             switch trans.transactionState {
>             case.purchased:
>                 print("buy ok, unlock IAP HERE")
>                 print(p.productIdentifier)
>                 
>                 let prodID = p.productIdentifier
>                 switch prodID {
>                     case "928.10883_2379":
>                         print("Payment Made")
>                         makeSuccessAlert()
>                     
>                     default:
>                         //in case in-app-payment id is not found
>                         print("IAP not found")
>                 }
>                 queue.finishTransaction(trans)
>             case .failed:
>                 print("buy error")
>                 queue.finishTransaction(trans)
>                 break;
>             default:
>                 print("Deafult")
>                 break
>             }
>         }
>         makeNewPage()
>     }
>     func makeNewPage(){
>         //created a function to activate the segue because it failed to work before
>         //The segue is a result of view to view connection
>         
>         self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "toMinutesKiinyaVC", sender: self)
>     }
>     func makeSuccessAlert(){
>         //Success Alert
>         let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Payment Made", message: "You payed for 15 mintue Tutoring", preferredStyle:
> ```
>
> UIAlertController.Style.alert)
> let okButton = UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: UIAlertAction.Style.default){
> action in
> self.dismiss(animated: true,completion: nil);
> }
> alert.addAction(okButton)
> self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
>
> ```
>     }
>             self.dismiss(animated: true,completion: nil);
>         }
>         alert.addAction(okButton)
>         self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
>         
>     }""
> ```

Comment: Please Help determine why my segue is failing to work properly

Answer (score 1):

Maybe try to perform segue on main thread

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {    
    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "toMinutesKiinyaVC", sender: self) 
}
```

Comment: Okay, I'll try that. To get this to work, I had to create a function called makeNewPage and called that function